# Android studio sdk does not contain any platforms

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I downloaded Android studio from their website for windows. It contained 790 Mb. But there is a message shown like

> SDK is missing

I followed answers for this issue of missing android studio SDK in here. But my problem is not solved yet. 
I have another problem. There is a message shown

> SDK does not contain any platforms

when I chose the SDK location by going to configure > project defaults > project structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be some files are not downloaded,try again with your internet connection.It will ask to download some additional files, press allow.

Answer (score 2):

this problem faced by almost everyone due to network problem .
You can easily resolve this error. I suggest you ,if any of your friends already installed android studio then copy sdk from him/her and paste into your sdk path and don't forget to delete sdk.
In this process ,your internet should work so that rest of the things it can download .
this is the best and easy way to resolve sdk error.After that you can download platform tools easily by going to settings>>Android sdk>> sdk tools.

Comment: Thankz. I will follow your method. .

Comment: hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the SDK Manager to download the NDK bundle.When your download completed, maybe there'r two different folders you have. One is ndk-bundle the other is ndk/22.0.7026061(the version you choose to download). And just use the behind one
2. As the log said before. Make sure you have config the ndk.dir in local.properties or the system global path variable.Or you also can open the project structure dialog to choose the Ndk location.Still use the behind folder( ndk/22.0.7026061).
3. If you have config it and still have the same problem.you can use the SDK Manager to download the NDK lower version one（like 21.0.6113669）.Cause it may not match to your AS version
4. Then repeat the step two

That's work nice for me